# Asymptotic Notations and forming Recurrence relations by analysing the algorithms

Tags: algorithm, recurrence

I went through many lectures, videos and sources regarding Asymptotic notations. I understood what O, Omega and Theta were. But in algorithms, why do we use only Big Oh notation always, why not Theta and Omega (I know it sounds noobish, but please help me with this). What exactly is this upperbound and lowerbound in accordance with Algorithms?

My next question is, how do we find the complexity from an algorithm. Say I have an algorithm, how do I find the recurrence relation T(N) and then compute the complexity out of it? How do I form these equations? Like in the case of Linear Search using Recursive way, T(n)=T(N-1) + 1. How?

It would be great if someone can explain me considering me a noob so that I can understand even better. I found some answers but wasn't convincing enough in StackOverFlow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we create an algorithm, it's always in order to be the fastest and we need to consider every case. This is why we use O, because we want to major the complexity and be sure that our algorithm will never overtake this.

To assess the complexity, you have to count the number of step. In the equation T(n) = T(n-1) + 1, there is gonna be N step before compute T(0), then the complixity is linear. (I'm talking about time complexity and not space complexity).

Answer (score 1):

**Why we use big-O so much compared to Theta and Omega:** This is partly cultural, rather than technical.  It is extremely common for people to say big-O when Theta would really be more appropriate.  Omega doesn't get used much in practice both because we frequently are more concerned about upper bounds than lower bounds, and also because non-trivial lower bounds are often much more difficult to prove.  (Trivial lower bounds are usually the kind that say "You have to look at all of the input, so the running time is at least equal to the size of the input.")

Of course, these comments about lower bounds also partly explain Theta, since Theta involves both an upper bound and a lower bound.

**Coming up with a recurrence relation:** There's no simple recipe that addresses all cases.  Here's a description for relatively simple recursive algorithmms.

Let N be the size of the initial input.  Suppose there are R recursive calls in your recursive function.  (Example: for mergesort, R would be 2.)  Further suppose that all the recursive calls reduce the size of the initial input by the same amount, from N to M.  (Example: for mergesort, M would be N/2.) And, finally, suppose that the recursive function does W work *outside of the recursive calls.*  (Example: for mergesort, W would be N for the merge.)

Then the recurrence relation would be T(N) = R*T(M) + W.  (Example: for mergesort, this would be T(N) = 2*T(N/2) + N.)